# issue with user defined methods executing

Tags: java, switch-statement, user-defined

Code no longer runs as I can't figure out how to get the scanner to run, but how do I get the methods to execute?
Tips and help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

For clarification, I want this code to run like a geometry calculator, however I do not really know how to call methods (which I think is the issue here)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;


public class Geometry
{
        private static void printMenu()
    {
                System.out.println("This is a geometry calculator");
                System.out.println("Choose what you would like to calculate");
                System.out.println("1. Find the area of a rectangle");
                System.out.println("2. Find the perimeter of a rectangle");
                System.out.println("3. Find the perimeter of a triangle");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of your choice:");
    }

 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
  int choice;   //the user's choice
  double value = 0; //the value returned from the method
  char letter;  //the Y or N from the user's decision to exit
  double radius;  //the radius of the circle
  double length;  //the length of the rectangle
  double width;  //the width of the rectangle
  double height;  //the height of the triangle
  double base;  //the base of the triangle
  double side1;  //the first side of the triangle
  double side2;  //the second side of the triangle
  double side3;  //the third side of the triangle

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
 }

    public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width, double value, Scanner keyboard) {
     System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
     length = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
     width = keyboard.nextDouble();
     value= length*width;
     System.out.println("The area of a rectangle is " + value);
     return value;
    }

    public static double rectanglePerimeter(double length, double width, double value, Scanner keyboard) {
     System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
     length = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
     width = keyboard.nextDouble();
     value= (2*length)+(2*width);
     System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + value);
     return value;
    }

    public static double trianglePerimeter(double side1, double side2, double side3, double value, Scanner keyboard) {
     System.out.print("Enter the length of side 1 of the triangle:  ");
     side1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.print("Enter the length of side 2 of the triangle:  ");
     side2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.print("Enter the length of side 3 of the triangle:  ");
     side3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
     //call the perimeter method and store the result in the value variable
     value = (side1 + side2 + side3);
     System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle is " + value);
     return value;

    //default:
     //System.out.println("You did not enter a valid choice.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by user-defined, please?

Comment: I think OP wants to move the entire `switch`/`case` statement into another `static` method.

Comment: Yes sorry, I want all 3 mathematical switches to separate static methods

Comment: Also, if you're looking to add additional functionality, I strongly recommend that you start using separately defined classes for each shape with a parent 'shape' class (or interface).

Comment: write separate methods for each mathematical functions and then call appropriate method in your switch case.

Comment: Please learn a basic Java tutorial before attempting to write any programs in it. You will learn how to format code and do basic things that you are asking SO for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you just want to encapsulate each of your cases in methods. Simply create a new method for each.

Example for case 2:

```
private static double rectanglePerimeter(Scanner keyboard) {
     System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
     double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
     double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
     double value= (2*length)+(2*width);
     System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + value);
     return value;
}
```

In your case block you would invoke it like:

```
switch (choice)
   {
    case 1:
     value = rectangleArea(keyboard);
     break;
    case 2:
     value = rectanglePerimeter(keyboard);
     break;
    case 3:
     value = trianglePerimeter(keyboard);
     break;
}
```

You can then refactor some of the variables out of main, such as length and width

Comment: This was upvoted before it was even a working solution :/

Comment: I'm about to post an updated version of the code

Comment: @GiannaCaruso Regarding your edited code, your don't nest your methods within your main, you invoke them within your switch statement. You still need to include your swtich/case structure.

Comment: I can't call the methods in the main and avoid a switch all together? @Grice

Comment: @GiannaCaruso You need a switch so that it knows what methods to invoke. Your simply moving the calculations out into separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Example method:

```
public static double calculateRectangleArea(Scanner keyboard){
    System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
    double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
    double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double value= length*width;
    System.out.println("The area of a rectangle is " + value);
    return value;
}
```

Example call:

```
case 1:
    value = calculateRectangleArea(keyboard);
    break;
```

Make sure to pass the `Scanner`.  You can do these for the other two cases.

So it should look more like this in the end:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Geometry
{
    private static void printMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("This is a geometry calculator");
        System.out.println("Choose what you would like to calculate");
        System.out.println("1. Find the area of a rectangle");
        System.out.println("2. Find the perimeter of a rectangle");
        System.out.println("3. Find the perimeter of a triangle");
        System.out.println("Enter the number of your choice:");
    }

    public static double calculateRectangleArea(Scanner keyboard){
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
        double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
        double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double value = length*width;
        System.out.println("The area of a rectangle is " + value);
        return value;
    }

    public static double calculateRectanglePerimeter(Scanner keyboard){
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
        double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
        double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double value = (2*length)+(2*width);
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + value);
        return value;
    }

    public static double calculateTrianglePerimeter(Scanner keyboard){
        System.out.print("Enter the length of side 1 of the triangle:  ");
        double side1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the length of side 2 of the triangle:  ");
        double side2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the length of side 3 of the triangle:  ");
        double side3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        //call the perimeter method and store the result in the value variable
        double value = (side1 + side2 + side3);
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle is " + value);
        return value;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int choice;   //the user's choice
        char letter;  //the Y or N from the user's decision to exit
        double value;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        do
        {
            //call the printMenu method
            printMenu();
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    value = calculateRectangleArea(keyboard);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = calculateRectanglePerimeter(keyboard);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    value = calculateTrianglePerimeter(keyboard);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You did not enter a valid choice.");
            }

            keyboard.nextLine(); //consumes the new line character after the number
            System.out.println("Do you want to exit the program (Y/N)?:  ");
            String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            letter = answer.charAt(0);
        }while (letter != 'Y' && letter != 'y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, now the calls should be in a separate switch statement?

Comment: This is helpful but I don't think I want void methods, I want them to return a value

Comment: @GiannaCaruso should be good now